# Android Compose NavHost popback to one of multiple instances of same destination chosen by route argument

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have a `NavHost` which contains a route with a single argument (like "name/{argument}") and navigate to this route multiple times in a row, each time with a different  argument. NavHost also contains a summary page, which should allow to go back to selected instance of aforementioned route (clearing the navigation stack up to this point), distinguished by argument that was passed to it. Unfortunately, when I use `NavigationController.popBackStack("route/argumentValue")` it seems to ignore the argument value and goes back to topmost instance of this route instead.

How could I achieve the intended behavior ?

Sample code:

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "startPage") {
        composable("startPage") {
            Column {
                Text("startPage")
                Button(onClick = {
                    navController.navigate("questionPage/aaa")
                    navController.navigate("questionPage/bbb")
                    navController.navigate("questionPage/ccc")
                    navController.navigate("questionPage/ddd")
                    navController.navigate("review")
                }) {
                    Text("test")
                }
            }
        }
        composable("questionPage/{questionId}") {
            val arg = it.arguments?.getString("questionId") ?: "---"
            Text("question: $arg")
        }
        composable("review") {
            Column {
                Text("review")
                Button(onClick = {
                    // opens page with "ddd" instead
                    navController.popBackStack("questionPage/bbb", false)
                }) {
                    Text("go back to bbb")
                }        
            }
        }
    }
}
```